# in Android 10, how to tracking an application's network statistics (netstats) using ADB

Tags: android, performance, adb

I use "adb shell cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats" to get my application's network statistics.

But it doesn't work in Android 10(Android Q), I got a `Permission denied`:

```
cat: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: Permission denied
```

so in Android 10, how to fix this problem?

Comment: That file actually no longer exists on Android 10. Have you found a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `service call netstats`

> adb shell service call netstats 11 i32 uid i32 0

```
private static final int TYPE_RX_BYTES = 0;
private static final int TYPE_RX_PACKETS = 1;
private static final int TYPE_TX_BYTES = 2;
private static final int TYPE_TX_PACKETS = 3;
private static final int TYPE_TCP_RX_PACKETS = 4;
private static final int TYPE_TCP_TX_PACKETS = 5;
```